# ¿Cómo eliminar los valores 0 del campo 'valor' de un pd.Serie con filas que son listas de diccionarios?

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

tengo el siguiente pd.Series llamado weights:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'valor': '43.4', 'data': '2022-02-10'}, {'valor': '46.6', 'data': '2022-03-28'}] |
| 1 | {'valor': '40.0', 'data': '2021-03-10'}, {'valor': '50', 'data': '2022-03-01'} |
| 2 | {'valor': '0', 'data': '2021-04-01'}, {'valor': '60', 'data': '2022-04-11'} |
| 3 | {'valor': '60.0', 'data': '2022-05-06'}, {'valor': '0', 'data': '2022-05-15'} |
| 4 | {'valor': '70.0', 'data': '2022-10-30'}, {'valor': '80', 'data': '2022-06-20'} |

Necesito eliminar los diccionarios que contiene 'valor': '0'.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
weights = [i for i in weights if list(i.values()) != [0]]
```

Pero me devuelve el error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'.

También he intentado:

```
for i in weights.copy():
if i['valor'] == '0': weights.remove(i)
```

Pero también me devuelve un error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

No encuentro la manera de solucionarlo sin obtener ningún tipo de error o consiguiendo que se eliminen los diccionarios con valor = 0.

Si alguien pudiera guiarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo la estructura de tus datos. Dices que es un `pd.Series`, pero la tabla que muestras parece más bien un `pd.DataFrame`. Por otro lado, los contenidos de la columna 0 ¿qué son? ¿Son meras cadenas de texto o son realmente estructuras de datos python? Si es lo segundo ¿qué tipo de estructura contienen? La primera fila parece tener una lista, pues está delimitada por `[ ... ]`, y dentro de esa lista un par de diccionarios. En cambio las filas siguientes ya no son listas, sino meros diccionarios separados por comas. ¿Seguro que está bien?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es primero asegurarnos que la columna de tu `dataframe` o en este caso la serie, pueda ser interpretada como una lista de diccionarios para poder iterar en cada "celda" o elemento de la columna o serie. Para lograrlo utilizamos [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Para implementarlo en una columna o serie podemos utilizar el método `apply()` de la siguiente forma:

```
columna.apply(literal_eval)
```

Si trabajamos con un `dataframe` podemos aplicarlo al leer los datos desde algún archivo, por ejemplo al leer los datos que pusiste en tu pregunta desde un archivo "sample2.csv" lo hacemos de la siguiente forma:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', sep=';', converters={'weights': literal_eval})
```

Para poder eliminar los diccionarios donde la llave `valor` sea `'0'` creamos la siguiente función:

```
def func(row):
    x = [i for i in row if i['valor'] != '0']
    return x
```

Y podemos aplicarla a la columna o serie con el método `apply()`

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', sep=';', converters={'weights': literal_eval})

def func(row):
    x = [i for i in row if i['valor'] != '0']
    return x

df['weights'] = df['weights'].apply(func)
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

|  | weights |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'valor': '43.4', 'data': '2022-02-10'}, {'valor': '46.6', 'data': '2022-03-28'}] |
| 1 | [{'valor': '40.0', 'data': '2021-03-10'}, {'valor': '50', 'data': '2022-03-01'}] |
| 2 | [{'valor': '60', 'data': '2022-04-11'}] |
| 3 | [{'valor': '60.0', 'data': '2022-05-06'}] |
| 4 | [{'valor': '70.0', 'data': '2022-10-30'}, {'valor': '80', 'data': '2022-06-20'}] |